# OBJ + MTL import not exporting textures on .FBX in batch mode using python script

Tags: python, export, unity, .fbx

I am importing a OBJ that has an corresponding MTL file in its folder. In Blender I am able to view this texture with ALT + Z. When I export the fbx file in blender GUI I am able to get the file with textures in Unity.

[image]

However, when I run the following python code in batch mode I see a object with no materials

```
def pipeline(objFilePath):

    bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath=objFilePath, filter_glob="*.obj;*.mtl", 
use_edges=True, use_smooth_groups=True, use_split_objects=True, use_split_groups=True,
use_groups_as_vgroups=False, use_image_search=True, split_mode='ON',
global_clamp_size=0, axis_forward='-Z', axis_up='Y')

    bpy.ops.object.select_by_type(type='MESH')

    bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_GEOMETRY')

    USER = os.environ['USER'];

    bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(filepath="/Users/"+USER+"/house.fbx", path_mode='RELATIVE', object_types={'MESH'})
```

[image]

In my Unity Project I have a texture folder with the appropriate textures for all my models.

What am I missing?